# Form.Left is offset by 7 pixels compared to the screen coordinates

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

I was having a lot of trouble with aligning where a pop-up menu should appear, when I grew really frustrated with not being able to pin down several pixels of an offset.

So I made a simple program that showed me just the current cursor position, and form window position, and I found that for some reason, the Form.Left coordinate is offset by 7? When I move the window to the very top left corner, the coordinates show -7,0, and when I move the window to 0,0 the window is offset by a few pixels to the right. See screenshots.

Can anyone explain this to me? Why is this happening, and if there's a way to fix it? Also, why is it not affecting the vertical position?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where does the form end up when you call `Left := 0; Top := 0;`?

Comment: First screenshot. With a few pixels of room to the left.

Comment: After you set to 0,0 by code verify the position by a 3rd party application, like WinSpy++. If the window is off then you likely have a DPI virtualization problem.

Comment: [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42491227/2292722) to a similar question sheds some light on the reasons and a possible workaround. Search for more examples with `window position Windows 10`

Comment: Ah that does look like the exact same issue. I tried searching for it but I guess I was using wrong keywords. Thanks!