Maximized JFrame's location is [-8,-8]. Can it be fixed?
My JFrame is misbehaving. When I maximize it (that is, call frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)), its location becomes [-8,-8] — even though it's not askew visually
I'm tasked with implementing a maximizable dialog in Swing. Many of our dialogs are "fat": they contain tables, forms, etc. So users want an option to maximize dialogs (and they don't want to manually resize them). I'm aware that Swing is not designed to operate on a native level (because the library belongs to Java, a cross-platform language). Still, it's a job I have to finish. I'm kind of stuck as once the dialog is maximized, its location is in a weird place, with noticeable gaps on the sides. I suspect it's because of the weird [-8,-8] location of its window ancestor which is set natively (in sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer#pShow). It's as if -8 for a frame actually means 0, while it means -8 for a dialog
Java 8. Windows 10
MRE:
package demos.panel;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Window;

public class FrameDemo {
    private static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        frame = new JFrame("Frame Demo");
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(createDebugButton());
        panel.add(createDialogButton());
        return panel;
    }

    private static JButton createDebugButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Print frame location");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("Frame's location: " + frame.getLocation());
        });
        return button;
    }

    private static JButton createDialogButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Show dialog");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            createDialog().setVisible(true);
        });
        return button;
    }

    private static JDialog createDialog() {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setContentPane(createDialogPane(dialog));
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        return dialog;
    }

    private static JPanel createDialogPane(JDialog dialog) {
        JPanel dialogPane = new JPanel();
        dialogPane.add(createMaximizeButton(dialog));
        return dialogPane;
    }

    private static JButton createMaximizeButton(JDialog dialog) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Maximize dialog");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            maximizeAndDisableResizing(dialog);
            // I won't make it a toggle, for the sake of simplicity,
            // so you'll have to rerun, sorry
            button.setEnabled(false);
        });
        return button;
    }

    private static void maximizeAndDisableResizing(Window window) {
        maximize(window);
        disableResizing(window);
    }

    private static void maximize(Window window) {
        Rectangle maximumPossibleBounds = getMaximumPossibleBounds();
        maximumPossibleBounds.setLocation(getTopmostContainerLocation(window));
        window.setBounds(maximumPossibleBounds);
    }

    private static Rectangle getMaximumPossibleBounds() {
        GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        return graphicsEnvironment.getMaximumWindowBounds();
    }

    private static Point getTopmostContainerLocation(Window window) {
        Window topmostContainer = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(window);
        Point location = (topmostContainer == null) ? new Point(0, 0) : topmostContainer.getLocation();
        return location;
    }

    private static void disableResizing(Window window) {
        ((Dialog) window).setResizable(false);
    }
}



Does this cause you any problem?

I get weird result even if the window is not maximized. For example, just create and show a window at location(0, 0). On my screen the left edge is 8 pixels in but the top edge is actually at the top. No idea what is going on behind the scenes. As a hack solution, just add 16 to the maximum width of the dialog and then set the location to (-8, 0). But, I also agree with the above comment.

@JustanotherJavaprogrammer sure, reread the question

That’s Microsoft Windows which accounts for the visible drag handles that used exist in Windows 3.0. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120326-00/?p=8003 But then, it also accounts for the fact that borders are entirely different in recent versions,  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42491227/2711488 for example. Don’t ask what happens when multiple monitors with different screen scaling settings are active…

@Holger thank you, that's interesting. Do you have any suggestions on how I can properly maximize a Swing dialog? If I just account for that invisible border, it may not work on other OSes (our customers may have all kinds of systems)

Maybe you’re better off just using a JFrame which has a genuine way to maximize it.

@Holger we gotta have modality and no extra icons in the task bar

The modality could be workarounded by opening an invisible Dialog in addition to the Frame, but I don’t know any solution for not showing it in the taskbar (yet). So it’s always a trade off…

Here is my effort.
(Notes after the code.)
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SwngTst0 implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  applicationWindow;

    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        applicationWindow = new JFrame("Application Window");
        applicationWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        applicationWindow.add(createButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        applicationWindow.pack();
        applicationWindow.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        applicationWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButton() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Show Dialog");
        button.addActionListener(this::showDialog);
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButton2() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Maximize");
        button.addActionListener(this::maximizeDialog);
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }

    private void maximizeDialog(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
        JDialog dlg = (JDialog) button.getTopLevelAncestor();
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        // Returned size is slightly less than actual [screen] size.
        // Hence explicitly increase as suitable.
        size.width += 8;

        dlg.setPreferredSize(size);
        dlg.pack();
    }

    private void showDialog(ActionEvent event) {
        JDialog dlg = new JDialog(applicationWindow, "Dialog");
        dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dlg.add(createButton2(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        dlg.pack();

        // By default, location of [top, left corner of] 'dlg' is (0,0).
        // 'dlg' should appear at top, left corner of screen.
        // However it does not.
        // Hence explicitly set location of 'dlg'.
        dlg.setLocation(new Point(-4, 0));

        dlg.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new SwngTst0());
    }
}

Here is how it looks with JDialog maximized.

This question gave me code for getting screen size and this question showed me how to set JDialog size.
Granted, it's not exactly what [I believe] you want but I assume that you will be able to modify it to suit your needs. I think you just need to experiment with parameter values for methods setLocation and setPreferredSize.
EDIT
Played around with the above code a bit more and realized the simple solution:- set the bounds of the JDialog to the bounds of its owner window.
To do this, I rewrote method maximizeDialog as:
private void maximizeDialog(ActionEvent event) {
    JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
    JDialog dlg = (JDialog) button.getTopLevelAncestor();
    dlg.setBounds(dlg.getOwner().getBounds());
}

Note that dlg has an owner window since I supplied one in the invocation of the JDialog constructor, i.e.
JDialog dlg = new JDialog(applicationWindow, "Dialog");

(Refer to method showDialog in the above code.)

Thank you. What is 8? What is -4?

@Cagepi I suggest that you try without calling method setLocation and without changing the Dimension returned by method getScreenSize in order to see how those things affect the size and location of the JDialog after it has been maximized. If it's still not clear after that, then let me know and I will explain in more detail.

Let me rephrase it. If you stored those ints in variables, what would you call those variables? What exactly do they represent? Anybody reading that would have that question

Btw, the gaps are still there on my machine. Just ran your code (though they are smaller)

@Cagepi did you miss this part of my answer? you just need to experiment with parameter values for methods setLocation and setPreferredSize

So you don't know what those values are, do you? You just tinkered with it till it kind of worked, didn't you (granted, some would say it's an accurate description of developers' job)?

Given the fact it's platform-dependent, this solution may not work well on other systems other than WIndows 10. I wonder if a truly cross-platform solution is possible (after all, we chose Java, a cross-platform language)

I'll give you a check mark since at this point, it's not apparent that a better (OS-independent) solution is possible. I will reassign the mark if some user will come up with something better. Again, thanks for your effort

@Cagepi thanks for showing your appreciation.

Here is a couple comments that could be worked into a solution.
I would use frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice().setFullScreenWindow(dialog); that will leave borders, but the code is very explicit.
To remove the border you can modify the maximizeDialog as follows.
private static void maximize(Window window) {
    
    
    JDialog test = new JDialog("loading");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    test.setContentPane(panel);
    test.setSize(256, 256);
    test.setVisible(true);
    
    //The size of the frame without decorations.        
    Rectangle content = panel.getBounds();
    
    test.dispose();
    
    int padX = 256 - (int)content.getWidth();
    int padY = 256 - (int)content.getHeight();

    //The frame is centered with handles on both sides.
    Rectangle orignal = window.getBounds();
    
    Rectangle fullScreen = new Rectangle(
        (int)original.getX() - padX/2,
        (int)original.getY(),
        (int)original.getWidth() + padX,
        (int)original.getWidth() + padX/2
    );
    
    window.setBounds(fullScreen);
    
}

That will make your screen flicker a little bit.

Thank you. Can you make the original example work (no gaps)?

You mean using the code you've provided + an undecorated dialog + full screen?

I need dialog decorations if they include window control buttons. Otherwise, yes

Okay, the "setUndecorated" is the reason there is no border so that isn't necessarily a solution for you. I can update the example to show how to use the decorations/no decorations to figure out some of the magic constants you mention.

@Cagepi I updated the answer and included a way to get the values for shifting the dialog. It is a complete compilable example.

Thank you. Though, I don't think it's very readable. My javac can compile it, but my brain can't

@Cagepi hah, you don't like using an int[] array to pass around the values. Fair assessment. I will update it with comments to make it clearer.

Always give code a chance to explain itself

@Cagepi You shouldn't write code that comments itself. People say that as a joke. Comments improve the quality. It should be understandable. You can call a value x and then have a comment or documentation that explains what x is.
